# Redirect API calls to local server in development mode and to remote server on production mode in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that runs on netlify lets say and a backend app that runs on AWS lets say. On my local development environment all API requests goes to local backend server which works perfectly fine. But what I want is to when I deploy my react and backend to production I want my react app to make requests to API end points on AWS server. Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be checking if we are currently on development or production and change endpoint based on this.
To do this you would need to check `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Now, I'm assuming you are using create-react-app, in this case you could follow [this documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables). However, if you dont use CRA then you might need to edit your Webpack config to achieve same same result.